# Style odd and even sibling elements - excluding those set to display:none

Tags: css, sass

Consider these elements:

```
<div class="accordion-content">
    <div><?php the_field('f_1'); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_field('f_2'); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_field('f_3'); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_field('f_4'); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_field('f_5'); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_field('f_6'); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_field('f_7'); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_field('f_8'); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_field('f_9'); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_field('f_10'); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_field('f_11'); ?></div>
</div>
```

and the styling

```
.accordion-content div:empty{display: none}

.accordion-content div:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color:#f0f0f1;
}

.accordion-content div:nth-of-type(even){
  background-color:#e1e1e4;
}
```

Link to static fiddle example http://codepen.io/whispering_jack/pen/yMWoZj

If the user enters data in the fields it will display the content otherwise if the field is empty it will not be displayed.

What I am trying to achieve is the alternating colors of the stripes, but the current css targets the non displayed elements as well and as a result if all the fields are not filled in the colors will not be alternating.

Can anyone suggest a solution to target only the displayed div alternating the background color? CSS or SCSS options welcome, js last resort.

Thanks.

EDIT: Still chasing some assistance on this.

Comment: Apply alternating the background color css  using `id` on displayed `div`.

Comment: Why not prevent the fields from printing using PHP?

Comment: @UtkarshDubey could you expand? With display:none the tags with no content will still be present in the code.

Comment: @Charlie I'm not sure exactly how to acheive this?

Comment: Is the page static? That is, do the contents of the page stay the same after it's been built? If so, then you can simply adjust the PHP to not echo the empty elements at all. That's what @Charlie means. Or, if the empty elements do need to be present, keep a counter in PHP that you reset whenever an element is empty and assign a class to every odd element.

Comment: @MrLister. The tags are static only the field data is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after some experimentation and working on a related problem the solution was to loop through the elements with jquery, if the spans were empty then .remove it from the dom. This then allows the div:empty class to fire.

Success!

EDIT:
Sample code as requested, ultra light dynamic accordion for Wordpress for use with Advanced Custom Fields, easily turn it into a plugin.

html

```
 <div class="accordion-content default">
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span></div>
    <div><span>Years on Council</span><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span></div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready( function($) {
//for this element, iterate each object
$('.accordion-content div').each(function(i, obj) {
    //the object
var $this = $(this);
    //if the object is empty
if ($this.find('span:empty').length) {
    //remove from dom (firing .element:empty:{display:none})
    $this.remove();
};
});


//Hide all the other panels except the first
$(".accordion-content:not(:first)").hide();
//onclick
$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

  //And, Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

});
});
//set the background color
var color="rgba(255,222,0,";
//change the background color of .element
function repaint() {
    //how many of this class?
  var all = $('.accordion-toggle').length,
      //opacity 1 - 10 divided by no. elements
      total = 10/all;
//iterate over each element
  $('.accordion-toggle').each(function(i){
        //countdown the elements and for each divide by total element by 10
    var opacity = (total*(all-i))/10,
            //join $opacity to $color and finish it
        newTone = color+opacity+")";
      //set the background color of the element to the new color
    $(this).css('background-color',newTone)
  })
}
repaint()
```

CSS

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## LIGHTWEIGHT ACCORDIAN
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#accordion{width:100%;margin: 0 20px}

#accordion .type-freeman{margin-bottom:0;}

.accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
.accordion-content {display: none;}
.accordion-content.default {display: block;}

.accordion-toggle{
  margin:0;
  padding:20px 20px;
}
.accordion-content div{margin:0;padding:16px 20px;}

.accordion-content div:empty{display: none}

.test{display: none}

.accordion-content div:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color:#f0f0f1;
}

.accordion-content div:nth-of-type(even){
  background-color:#e1e1e4;
}


.accordion-content div span:first-of-type{
 text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%
}

.accordion-content div span:last-of-type{
 text-align: right;
     display: inline-block;
    width: 50%
}
```

Comment: Maybe add some sample code so others can implement it or suggest a better performing method

Comment: @Mauro Just added the finished product if your interested.

Comment: @JBP thanks, I haven't need of it but someone might, remember to accept the solution as the accepted answer when you can.

Comment: It wont let me accept my own solution for two days : |